# Trying to create a reaction on a message by using its Id. - discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

By the tests I made, the emoji to react is fine, but it is reacting to the command message, not the message I specified the Id.

```
module.exports = {
name: 'cargo',
description: 'Give a role to an user by reaction',
execute(message, args) {
    const messageId = args.slice(0, 1);
    const roleEmoji = args.slice(1);
    const fetchMessage = message.channel.fetch(`${messageId}`)
    //const roleGive = MessageMentions.roles;
    console.log('\x1b[35m%s\x1b[0m','messageId:', messageId,'roleEmoji:', roleEmoji)
    message.channel.messages.fetch(`${messageId}`).then(() => message.react(`${roleEmoji}`));
    message.channel.send(`${messageId}, ${roleEmoji}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were calling react on the wrong message, this should solve your issue.

```
module.exports = {
name: 'cargo',
description: 'Give a role to an user by reaction',
execute(message, args) {
    const messageId = args.slice(0, 1);
    const roleEmoji = args.slice(1);
    const fetchMessage = message.channel.fetch(`${messageId}`)
    //const roleGive = MessageMentions.roles;
    console.log('\x1b[35m%s\x1b[0m','messageId:', messageId,'roleEmoji:', roleEmoji)
    message.channel.messages.fetch(`${messageId}`).then(msg => msg.react(`${roleEmoji}`));
    message.channel.send(`${messageId}, ${roleEmoji}`);
}
```